# FancyBox 1.3.4 jquery issue in IE8 and IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, joomla1.5

I was hoping that someone can help me with this fancybox plugin issue.

Problem is in the IE7 and IE8.
Error - SCRIPT87: Could not get the display property. Invalid argument.

As I noticed scripts break on this line:

```
            $(fx).animate({prop: 1}, {
                 duration : currentOpts.speedIn,
                 easing : currentOpts.easingIn,
                 step : _draw,
                 complete : _finish
            });
```

I'm using jquery version 1.4.2

live example and issue on this link:
http://goo.gl/x0rF7

Comment: Very strange, could be a bug with the minified version of that jQuery version. I debugged that line and the object has the display property. But the whole minified statement isn't working. Are you able to update to the latest version of jQuery and see if it still happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed.

Not the best way but it working

```
$(fx).animate({prop: 1}, {
                 duration : currentOpts.speedIn,
                 easing : currentOpts.easingIn,
                 step : _draw,
                 complete : _finish
            });
```

I removed all animation and just wrote

```
_finish();
```

Thanks for the answer JFK, I tryed with that but no

Answer (score 1):

You are adding 3 instances of jQuery when you only need one (ideally the latest version): http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

http://www.crystalhotel-belgrade.rs/test/plugins/content/simplepopup/jquery-1.4.3.min.js

and an empty call to
http://www.crystalhotel-belgrade.rs/test/jomres/javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

.....Also you are loading jQuery UI twice

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js

http://www.crystalhotel-belgrade.rs/test/jomres/javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js

IE is more susceptible to this kind of conflicts/errors than other browsers. Try reducing your calls to a single instance of each script and beware of the order (jQuery first and jQuery plugins after)

Additionally, make sure that the DOCTYPE is the very first line of your html document (not preceding spaces or comments), otherwise IE will fail to run in standards mode hence fancybox won't work properly.

Comment: Thanks for quick the answer. I tried with your suggestion and still has issue.

Comment: Could you specify what exactly the issue is? ... I see fancybox popping up on page load (with no content due to a path issue), otherwise I don't see any other error